# ld: library not found for -lqt-mt

Tags: qt

I tried to build a QT program, but I got this error: "ld: library not found for -lqt-mt".

please what is this lib, and how I can fix this problem.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=558637